# Constraint animation issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, nslayoutconstraint

I'm building an app whereas I'm facing a strange issue with constraints.

I'm trying to animate a height constraint attached to a `UIView` in storyboard, but the simulator displays some weird behaviour. To debug, I created a completely new, iOS 9.2 project and added a `UIButton`, set up a horizontal pin and superview top constraint to it, linked the top constraint to my header file and the button itself to an `IBAction`.

When calling this code alone:

```
- (IBAction)myAction:(id)sender {
    self.topConstraint.constant += 150.0f;
}
```

The button snaps 150 points down, even without calling `[self.view layoutIfNeeded];`.

However, when I'm using this code:

```
- (IBAction)myAction:(id)sender {
    self.topConstraint.constant += 150.0f;
    [self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}
```

The button slides down.

**How come it snaps there without me calling `layoutIfNeeded` when there's no animation block?** I find this very strange.

Here's my header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *topConstraint;

@end
```

And my top `NSLayoutConstraint` setup:

[image]

And the `UIViewController` in interface builder:
[image]

Comment: you dont need to call set needsto update constraints when you do layout if needed!!!

Comment: @Mr.T, I see - I'll change it. Thank you for feedback. Do you have an idea of why the problem I'm facing is occurring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling layoutIfNeeded on a view merely forces an update of the view early, rather than waiting for an update through the drawing cycle, when you animate your constraint you are placing the layoutIfNeeded inside the animation block thus animating the change, in the 2nd instance where you do not call layoutIfNeeded, the drawing cycle comes around and updates the view without animation.

Comment: I see. Would it be more appropriate to put the constant changing code inside the animation block alongisde `layoutIfNeeded`?

Comment: I'm confused if you want it to 'snap', only set the constant, if you want it to animate change the constant and call layoutIfNeeded inside the animation block in the same method.

Comment: I want it to animate, but you answered the question with your comment. I wanted to know if I should change the constant along with calling `layoutIfNeeded` in the same animation block

Comment: Putting the constant in the animation block isn't necessary. There's nothing to animate. After you change the constant of the constraint, and the view is updated, the constraints are read and the view is changed accordingly.